# SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'if'

Tags: javascript, eris

```
var Eris = require('eris')
var bot = new Eris("########")                        

bot.on("ready", () =>(
    console.log("to vivo pai ihihihi")
));

bot.on("messageCreate"), (msg) => (
    if(msg.content.indexof(!ajuda) == 0) {
        bot.createmessage(msg.channel.id, "123")
    }
)); 

bot.connect()
```

> i'm newbie to javascript and i was having this error can someone help me? (i'm using eris)
> PS:the "new Eris("########")" was supposed to be a token but i censored him

Comment: The syntax you've used with parens is for return something from a function, but then you're using an `if` statement, which is invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a parens when it should be a curly brace for an arrow function:

```js
bot.on("messageCreate"), (msg) => { // <--- curly brace, not parens
    if(msg.content.indexof(!ajuda) == 0) {
        bot.createmessage(msg.channel.id, "123")
    }
}); // <---- again, curly brace, not parens
```